# Server closes TCP connection via FIN, ACK and RST immediatelly after establishing it

Tags: java, macos, tomcat, tcp

On a Mac OS X 10.8 machine I have a Tomcat 7.0.40 Server and a client, both running locally. Via 3-way-handshake a TCP connection is established, followed immediately by FIN, ACK and RST from server. Client receives "End of file from server", or "Connection reset".

TCP sequence:

client SYN
server SYN, ACK
client ACK

server [TCP Window Update] ACK
server FIN, ACK
client ACK
server [TCP Dup ACK] ACK
client GET /myurl/...
server RST

Details
- client and server both run locally
- first GET request fails. Following requests succeed.
- no firewall in on
- maxfiles already increased, in vain

What causes that the server closes the socket? Appreciate tips and ideas.

EDIT: Tomcat's log has the following stack traces:

```
    FINE: Error parsing HTTP request header
    java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:501)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.parseRequestLine(InternalInputBuffer.java:98)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:928)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

and

```
    Aug 14, 2013 5:15:17 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor process
    FINE: Error parsing HTTP request header
    java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.setRequestLineReadTimeout(Http11Processor.java:174)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:926)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with tomcat, but do you have some kind of trace log with more detailed information?

Answer (score 0):

You must be either violating a configured access rule such as an IP address blacklist, or else sending it something that it doesn't understand.

Comment: The same app runs fine with JDK 6 on the same Mac. I suspect the problem may be due to JDK 1.7.0_25.